# InvalidCastException exception when reading from session state

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I debug my Web Site project in Visual Studio 2013 I get an issue when I try and cast a Session item to a specific type (ZZZZ).

```
return (ZZZZ) Session["SessionItem"];
```

An InvalidCastException is thrown with the following content

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in
>   App_Code.axv-bzrg.dll but was not handled in user code
>        Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'XXX.YYYY.ZZZZ' to type 'XXX.YYYY.ZZZZ'.

I added a watch item for

```
(WebUser) Session["LoggedInUser"]
```

And the following was displayed in the Value part of the watch:

> The type 'XXX.YYYY.ZZZZ' exists in both 'App_Code.axv-bzrg.dll' and
>   'App_Code.ys_ymegf.dll'

I navigated to the Temporary ASP.NET Files folder

> C:\Users_________\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\dc8aa7ce\b2661c39

And the two DLL files were in there. I think the App_Code DLLs are generated on each page request, but the previous ones are NOT being removed causing there to be two duplicated types in the Temp directory. Why is this happening and how can I go about fixing this?

Comment: Stopping IIS and clearing all \Temporary ASP.NET Files\ often fixes it. More rarely a clean/rebuild fixes it.

Comment: You are correct it does, but I can't stop IIS or rebuild every time (it will be impossible to debug). Also, removing Temporary files is possible but extremely annoying and unproductive. Also, I don't have a Clean option for this project. Any guess why that might be?

Comment: Clean solution should be on the context menu. Clean recompiles everything, including things that Visual Studio thinks don't need a recompile.

It's been a while, but sometime this happens when the dynamic compiler doesn't like how you set up the directives in your markup.

Another more drastic solution is to switch from a WebSite to a WebApplication, which has more predictable compilation/less quirky, especially as the project size gets larger.

Answer (score 2):

This is somewhat expected behavior.

You navigate to page first time - object added to session state with type `page_V1.dll:MyType`.

You decide to touch source of the page to fix something - since it does not kill session cookies navigating to the same page again will try to get object from in-memory session state (session state is not lost as app pool not restarted due to just page changes). Your page at that point compiled again and now tries to case type stored in the session to new type `page_v2.dll:MyType` which indeed fail as types are not related to each other (even if they are identical otherwise).

Fix:

- for debugging purposes - start new browser session / clear cookies or just trigger app-pool recycle (i.e. by touching web.Config).
- consider moving objects to class library project and adding reference to it from web site - this way you control when types are actually re-compiled and thus will not lose identity due to dynamically generated assembly file name.