# c# .net invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

c# .net invalid cast exception:

> [A]GroupReference cannot be cast to [B]GroupReference. Type A
>   originates from 'App_Code.d7jdf1ji, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\26676eb7\92c7e946\App_Code.d7jdf1ji.dll'. Type B originates
>   from 'App_Code.t8v3riip, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' in the context 'Default' at location
>   'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\root\26676eb7\92c7e946\App_Code.t8v3riip.dll'

Here is my code

```
public partial class packages : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    GroupReference gr_object;
    DataConnect dc_object;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gr_object = (GroupReference)Session["GroupReference"];
        dc_object = (DataConnect)Session["DataConnect"];
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        Page.EnableViewState = false;

        Welcome.Text = "packages end date is the day it is requested.<br/><br/>";
        Data.init();

        HideControls();
        packages();
        packagess_Grid_Active.Visible = true;
        packages_Grid_Inactive.Visible = true;
        SaveAsExcelButton_Active.Visible = true;
        SaveAsExcelButton_Inactive.Visible = true;
        ShowControls();

        Usage.RecordUse("packages");
    }
}
protected void packages()
{

    OracleConnection oc = dc_object.oc_object.Connect();
    OracleCommand ocmd = new OracleCommand();
    OracleDataReader dr;
    ocmd.Connection = oc;

    ocmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from packages"; 
    ocmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    dr = ocmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want to say that you have a class in 2 different assemblies that happen to have the same name but are in fact 2 different classes because they are in 2 different assemblies

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30267116/debugging-issue-in-visual-studio-2013-with-duplicated-dll/30267269#30267269

Comment: @RadioSpace 99% it is not the case - likely caused by ASP.Net not restarting AppDomain on partial re-compiles.

Comment: you should describe your problem more.

Comment: @RadioSpace i got u, i have deleted the copy file this above .cs file which i kept for back up if i mess up which has  the same class name ...which was the main reason behind the error thank you very much for helping me out .!! now it works fine after i have removed that file (y)

Answer (score 0):

i have deleted the copy file of this above .cs file which i kept for back up in case i mess up which has the same class name ...which was the main reason behind the error thank you very much for helping me out .!! now it works fine after i have removed that file...

Thanks to every1 specially RadioSpace for guiding me ..!!

Comment: if you goto properties you can mark it not to compile. but really you should use some form of source/version control.